# Thread safety for taking screenshots on Windows with C++ Builder

Tags: c++, thread-safety, c++builder, vcl

Isn't taking a screenshot on Windows thread-safe?

My following code sometimes takes some shots, but in most cases, the *imgScreenshot* (which is just a TImage) keeps being just plain white...

Am I missing something?

```
void __fastcall TCaptureThread::Execute()
{
    int CurWidth = 1600;
    int CurHeight = 900;

    std::unique_ptr<TCanvas> Canvas(new TCanvas);
    Canvas->Handle = GetDC(0);    

    FBMP = new TBitmap;                     // private class field
    FBMP->Width     = CurWidth;
    FBMP->Height    = CurHeight;    

    FR = Rect(0, 0, CurWidth, CurHeight);   // private class field

    while(!Terminated)
    {
        FBMP->Canvas->CopyRect(FR, Canvas, FR);       
        Synchronize(&UpdatePicture);

        Sleep(100);                 
    }

    delete FBMP;
    FBMP = NULL;
}

void __fastcall TCaptureThread::UpdatePicture()
{
    FMainForm->imgScreenshot->Canvas->CopyRect(FR, FBMP->Canvas, FR);
}
```

Environment is C++ Builder 10.1.2 Berlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't taking a screenshot on Windows thread-safe?

Not when using VCL wrapper classes that are not thread-safe by default.  If you were using plain Win32 API functions directly, then yes, it would be possible to write thread-safe code.

The main reason your code fails is because the VCL is designed to share GDI resources between multiple objects, and the main UI thread frequently frees unused/dormant GDI resources.  So your worker thread's `TBitmap` image data is likely to get destroyed before you can call `Synchronize()` to copy it to your `TImage`.

That being said, what you are attempting *can* be done if you call `Lock()`/`Unlock()` on the `Canvas` objects in your worker thread, eg:

```
struct CanvasLocker
{
    TCanvas *mCanvas;
    CanvasLocker(TCanvas *C) : mCanvas(C) { mCanvas->Lock(); }
    ~CanvasLocker() { mCanvas->Unlock(); }
};

void __fastcall TCaptureThread::Execute()
{
    int CurWidth = 1600;
    int CurHeight = 900;

    std::unique_ptr<TCanvas> Canvas(new TCanvas);
    std::unique_ptr<TBitmap> BMP(new TBitmap);
    FBMP = BMP.get();

    {
    CanvasLocker lock(Canvas); // <-- add this!
    Canvas->Handle = GetDC(0);    
    }

    {
    CanvasLocker lock(BMP->Canvas); // <-- add this!
    BMP->Width = CurWidth;
    BMP->Height = CurHeight;    
    }

    FR = Rect(0, 0, CurWidth, CurHeight);

    while (!Terminated)
    {
        {
        CanvasLocker lock1(Canvas); // <-- add this!
        CanvasLocker lock2(BMP->Canvas); // <-- add this!
        BMP->Canvas->CopyRect(FR, Canvas.get(), FR);
        }

        Synchronize(&UpdatePicture);

        Sleep(100);                 
    }
}

void __fastcall TCaptureThread::UpdatePicture()
{
    CanvasLocker lock1(FBMP->Canvas); // <-- add this!
    CanvasLocker lock2(FMainForm->imgScreenshot->Canvas); // <-- add this!

    FMainForm->imgScreenshot->Canvas->CopyRect(FR, FBMP->Canvas, FR);
    // or: FMainForm->imgScreenshot->Picture->Bitmap->Assign(FBMP);
}
```

That being said, because `TCanvas` is lockable, you *might* be able to get away with removing `Synchronize()` altogether:

```
void __fastcall TCaptureThread::Execute()
{
    int CurWidth = 1600;
    int CurHeight = 900;

    std::unique_ptr<TCanvas> Canvas(new TCanvas);
    std::unique_ptr<TBitmap> BMP(new TBitmap);

    {
    CanvasLocker lock(Canvas);
    Canvas->Handle = GetDC(0);    
    }

    {
    CanvasLocker lock(BMP->Canvas);
    BMP->Width = CurWidth;
    BMP->Height = CurHeight;    
    }

    TRect r = Rect(0, 0, CurWidth, CurHeight);

    while (!Terminated)
    {
        {
        CanvasLocker lock1(BMP->Canvas);

        {
        CanvasLocker lock2(Canvas);
        BMP->Canvas->CopyRect(r, Canvas.get(), r);
        }

        CanvasLocker lock3(FMainForm->imgScreenshot->Canvas);
        FMainForm->imgScreenshot->Canvas->CopyRect(r, BMP->Canvas, r);
        // or: FMainForm->imgScreenshot->Picture->Bitmap->Assign(BMP);
        }

        Sleep(100);                 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Remy, for this very detailed answer. I got it up and running by locking the canvasses as mentioned but synchronizing s still a must. I got some random AVs without it. (by the end way: I definitely like your "local section RAII".